# Excel, SAS, Python, factor level combination

Tags: python, excel, sas, combinations

I have 4 factors A B C D, each factor has different levels which named as
A1 A2 B1 B2 B3  C1 C2 C3 D1 D2 D3 D4
How can I can the factor combinations for each level: A1B1C1D1 A1B1C1D2 A1B1C1D3 A1B1C1D4 A2 B1 C1D1 …..etc. There should be 2x3x4x4 of such combination.

I can use Excel, SAS or Python, but I don't know the solution. Thank you for advises.

Comment: May I suggest that you use [statsmodels ols](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS.html) with the [patsy language](https://patsy.readthedocs.io/en/v0.1.0/formulas.html) to encode the linear model. If you have difficulty doing that then please feel free to put a specific question about that here on StackOverflow.

Comment: If you're looking to create a design matrix, then I would suggest SAS PROC GLMMOD which will create the matrix for you.

Comment: Oh, and if you're running models in SAS, there are ways to specify all these interactions without actually creating all the different possible combinations using shorthand notations. As stated this question doesn't really have enough information to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SAS

```
data want;
format A B C D $2.;
format combination $8.;
do aa=1 to 2;
   A = catt("A",aa);
   do bb=1 to 3;
      B = catt("B",bb);
      do cc=1 to 3;
         C = catt("C",cc);
         do dd=1 to 5;
            D = catt("D",dd);
            combination=catt(A,B,C,D);
            output;
         end;
      end;
   end;
end;
drop aa bb cc dd;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python:

```
for a in range(1,3):
   for b in range(1,4):
      for c in range(1,5):
         for d in range(1,5):
            print "A%d B%d C%d D%d" % (a,b,c,d)
```

You could also put the names of the factors and the numbers of levels in lists and use a recursive function:

```
factors = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
levels = [2, 3, 4, 4]

def recurse(i, combination):
   if i < len(factors):
      for level in range(1, levels[i]+1):
         concat = factors[i] + str(level)
         recurse(i+1, combination+concat)
   else:
      print combination

recurse(0, '')
```

You may even include the level names in the factor list, like this:

```
factorlist = [['A', '1', '2'], ['B', '1', '2', '3'], ['C', '1', '2', '3', '4'], ['D', '1', '2', '3', '4']]

def recurse(i, combination):
   if i < len(factorlist):
      for level in range(1, len(factorlist[i])):
         concat = factors[i][0] + factorlist[i][level]
         recurse(i+1, combination+concat)
   else:
      print combination

recurse(0, '')
```

Comment: Or... `for levels in itertools.product(range(1,3), range(1,4), range(1,5), range(1, 5)): print('A{} B{} C{} D{}'.format(*levels)`... ?

Comment: I tried product and it works! @Jon,   Jos please see Jon's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using Excel VBA:

```
Sub user()
    ZZ = 1
    For i = 1 To 4
        For j = 1 To 4
            For k = 1 To 4
                For l = 1 To 4
                    Cells(ZZ, 1) = "A" & i & "B" & j & "C" & k & "D" & l
                    ZZ = ZZ + 1
                Next l
            Next k
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

will produce all 256 items:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you collect all level name in a list like :

```
data=['A1', 'A2' ,'B1' ,'B2', 'B3' ,'C1' ,'C2' ,'C3' ,'D1' ,'D2', 'D3' ,'D4']
```

Now if you use this code to find unique elements in list :

```
track={}
for i in data:
    if int(list(i)[1]) not in track:
        track[int(list(i)[1])]=[i]
    else:
        track[int(list(i)[1])].append(i)
```

at last just generate combinations using itertools with r=len(unique_elements)  , r = length tuples

```
import itertools

print(list(itertools.combinations(data,r=len(track))))
```

full code:

```
data=['A1', 'A2' ,'B1' ,'B2', 'B3' ,'C1' ,'C2' ,'C3' ,'D1' ,'D2', 'D3' ,'D4']

track={}
for i in data:
    if int(list(i)[1]) not in track:
        track[int(list(i)[1])]=[i]
    else:
        track[int(list(i)[1])].append(i)



import itertools

print(list(itertools.combinations(data,r=len(track))))
```

output:

```
('A1', 'A2', 'B1', 'B2'), ('A1', 'A2', 'B1', 'B3'), ('A1', 'A2', 'B1', 'C1'), ('A1', 'A2', 'B1', 'C2'), ('A1', 'A2', 'B1', 'C3')....
```